# Is there a way in Linux to have one non root user check if another non root user has permissions to a folder / file?

Tags: permissions, files

The scenario is this - I have a command line program that might not run as root, part of the requirements is to warn if another user has write permissions to some folder / file

e.g.

- I'm running as non root user A
- I would like to get the answer to the question: "does user B has write permissions to folder F"

So my questions are

- Is it even possible to do as a root user? if so how?
- Is there any way to do it as a non root user?

Comment: This is actually hard to answer in general. For example, the answers here fail to consider ACLs. They also fail to consider user/group mapping that may occur on a network share.

Answer (score 6):

In general, the only way to know if user B can write to directory D is for user B to attempt to write to directory D.

So, as root, you can `su` to the user and try it. Though that may not be 100% accurate as the user logging in and entering his password may change things (e.g., a pam module might set up crypto keys based on the user's password).

Almost as accurate, again as root, you can `su` to the user and use the `access(2)` syscall or similar. Probably, this is what the shell does if you use `test -w`, and also be what `/usr/bin/test` does. Though as the manpage warns, on NFSv2, the *actual* check is done by the server, but the test for the `access` syscall is done locally, so it may be wrong. Similarly, FUSE filesystems may do the same.

(The `access(2)` manpage also mentions a race condition which is fundamental to what you're doing: B's permissions on D might change between when you check and when B actually tries to write to D.)

Other than that, you have to decide how accurate you are willing to accept:

1. You could stat the directory, and check the users & groups (as several of the other answers show)
2. You could additionally check the ACLs on the directory.

But even if you do that, the following will trip you up:

1. With NFS and various other network filesystems, the *server* decides if access is permitted. It can make that decision based on, well, whatever it likes. Consider e.g., the various squash NFS export options.
2. Permissions checks are actually done by the filesystem; non-Unix filesystems may give unexpected answers (how is the Unix user mapped to a SID for NTFS?). All bets are off with e.g., FUSE filesystems.

Comment: +1 FUSE filesystems mounted with `--allow-other` are world writable regardless of file mode.

Comment: "the only way to know if user B can write to directory D is for user B to attempt to write to directory D" What has `access(2)/faccessat(2)` been invented for then and why is it so heavily used? `strace -e trace=faccessat bash -c 'test -w /tmp'`

Comment: @HaukeLaging `access`/etc. don't always work, though they're much closer. See the last paragraph under "NOTES" in the access(2) manpage: *These  calls  may not work correctly on NFSv2 filesystems with UID mapping enabled, because UID mapping is done on the server and hidden from
       the  client, which checks permissions.  (NFS versions 3 and higher per‐
       form the check on the server.)  Similar  problems  can  occur  to  FUSE
       mounts.* I'll add in a note about it, though.

Comment: @HaukeLaging note added.

Comment: I would go so far as to say that all uses of `access` should be assumed to be bugs until proven otherwise; I'm not sure I've *ever* seen a situation, even in a setuid program, where it was the Right Thing.

Comment: Indeed, `access` is almost always a bug. It's subject to TOCTOU races and it uses the real uid/gid rather than the effective (or, if it's set differently, the Linux-specific fsuid/fsgid) uid/gid to determine permissions, which is almost never what you want unless they all happen to be equal.

Answer (score 4):

> "does user B has write permissions to folder F"

User A's ability to determine this hinges on A's access to folder F.  For example, if F is `/home/B/foo/bar` and A cannot read `/home/B/foo`, then A cannot even check if F exists, much less what permissions are set on it.

Presuming A does have read access to F, and can therefore `stat()`<sup>1</sup> it to get the permissions, the next step is to determine if B is the owner, or in the group.  With regard to the latter, you can get a list of users in the group with `getgrent()` (native C -- it has a man page; note this does not take an argument but instead iterates `/etc/group` one entry at a time), which returns a `struct group`:

```c
       struct group {
           char   *gr_name;       /* group name */
           char   *gr_passwd;     /* group password */
           gid_t   gr_gid;        /* group ID */
           char  **gr_mem;        /* group members */
       };
```

The last field, `gr_mem`, is an array of strings containing the list of user names (this list is terminated with a `NULL` pointer).  That, combined with the file mode, is enough information to tell you whether a particular user has write permission.

An example using `getgrent()`, to print a list of groups with IDs and members:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <grp.h>

// std=c99

int main (void) {
    struct group *ent = getgrent();
    while (ent) {
        printf (
            "%s GID %d\n",
            ent->gr_name,
            ent->gr_gid
        );
        int i = 0;
        char *p = ent->gr_mem[i];
        while (p) {
            printf("\t%s\n", p);
            p = ent->gr_mem[++i];
        }
        ent = getgrent();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Access to `/etc/group` (and use of `getgrent()`) does not require privileges.

<sup>1 You do not mention what language you are using, but hopefully "stat" is reasonably agnostic.  `getgrent()` should be mostly be ported too, but to what depends on the language.</sup>

Comment: "A cannot read /home/B/foo, then A cannot even check if F exists" oh yes, A can do that. A cannot if A has no **execute** permission for `foo`...

Comment: @HaukeLaging No, if A does not have *read* (plus execute) permissions on `/foo`, A cannot check if a subfolder of `/foo` exists.  Note I didn't mention the mode, I just said "can read" (as opposed to "has read permissions"). WRT read access on `/foo`'s subfolder (so F =`/foo/bar`), that's all that's required to stat() it. So A does not actually need execute permissions on F.

Comment: Sure you can check whether a **certain** subfolder (or file) exists. You just cannot read the list of directory entries. You must know the path you want to check.

Comment: @goldilocks it's `<!-- language: lang-c -->`. Fixed it for you.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Playing around, it seems you can stat a filepath that you have *no permissions* on **BUT** to do that you need *execute* on the folder it's in.  So that applies to the parent of F, point taken!

Answer (score 2):

Answer to the first question (running as root):

YES -> `su - userB -c '<command as userB to touch file in folderF>'`

Answer to the second question:

MAYBE -> only if non user is within the same group as userB and tries to touch a file in folderF

Comment: Don't use `sudo su`. If you want a shell, do `sudo -s`, else just use `sudo` regularly.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I tested with my own user so I had do `sudo su`, but you're right!

Comment: Again, you do not need `sudo su` for this purpose. Take a look at `sudo -u`. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a single command to fulfill this purpose, but there are several commands that would allow you to determine the answer without root.

`ls -l F` will show you the owner and group of the file in-question. If the user is not the owner, then you can check `groups user` to see if the user belongs to the file's group. If the userB is either the owner, or belongs to the file's group, then the access permissions for `u` and `g` (respectively) will tell you what permissions they have; else, the access permissions for `o` will tell you what permissions the user has.

Comment: I just say: ACLs...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, you need to check the user permission on a particular folder.

So basically first run the groups command on the user.

```
groups userB
```

The above command will list all the groups that the `userB` belong to. After that,

Use the `stat` command to find the octal permissions on the *file/folder* as below.

```
stat -c "%a %n" /some-folder
```

The above command will return the octal permission on that particular *folder*/*file*.

For example, if the above command returns **775**, it means `user` and `group` have full `rwx` access on the *file/folder* `others` have `r-x` access on the *file/folder*.

Determine the groups of *userA* as well using `groups userA` command and if both *userA* and *userB* belong to the same group then it means *userB* has **write** permissions on the file.